# split html by tags

Tags: c, split

I want to split a html page into pieces by a tag delimiter: like `<img` or `<div>`.
I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
char source[MAXBUFLEN + 1];
FILE *fp = fopen("source.html", "r");
if (fp != NULL)
{
    size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), MAXBUFLEN, fp);
    if (newLen == 0) {
        fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
    } else {
        source[++newLen] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
    }
}
fclose(fp);

//not working
char* strArray[10];
int i = 0;
char *token = strtok(source, "<img");
while(token != NULL)
{
    strcpy(strArray[i++], token);

    token = strtok(NULL, "<img");
}

printf("%s\n", strArray[3]);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other method I can use except strtok?

Comment: The second argument of `strtok()` is actually a list of all the delimiters you're interested in. I would recommend splitting on "<" and then checking if the token begins with `img`

Comment: Unless you really need to implement this yourself I would suggest you check out libxml: http://www.xmlsoft.org/ . Otherwise you will have to use strtok to parse for "<", then test your tag and then parse for ">".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daren has already posted, `strtok()` doesn't do what you want. You can use

```
char *ptr = strstr( source, "<img" );
```

instead to find the first tag, and then

```
ptr = strstr(ptr+4, "<img" ); // search starts direcly behind the previous "<img" 
                              // maybe you can find a better offset
```

for the next occurances.

Besides, your line

```
strcpy(strArray[i++], token);
```

would crash because you have no memory allocated to the pointer.

Comment: yes, you're right, now it extracts correctly but the part where I want to add to an array all the results doesn't work. I only need the 4th element from array. Do you know any other way to save only the 4th occurrence without using an array? thanks

Comment: do you mean the 4th <img> tag? Then you could just do a loop like `for( i=0; ptr=source; i<4 && (ptr=strstr(ptr,"<img")) != NULL; i++,ptr+=4 );`. If `ptr != NULL` afterwards you have found your tag.

Comment: and it says what? Oops, I've just seen one error: replace `i=0; ptr=source` by `i=0, ptr=source`. Both belongs to the initialization part of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *strtokByWord_r(char *str, const char *word, char **store){
    char *p, *ret;
    if(str != NULL){
        *store = str;
    }
    if(*store == NULL) return NULL;
    p = strstr(ret=*store, word);
    if(p){
        *p='\0';
        *store = p + strlen(word);
    } else {
        *store = NULL;
    }
    return ret;
}
char *strtokByWord(char *str, const char *word){
    static char *store = NULL;
    return strtokByWord_r(str, word, &store);
}
```

replace

```
char *token = strtok(source, "<img");
...
token = strtok(NULL, "<img");
```

to

```
char *token = strtokByWord(source, "<img");
...
token = strtokByWord(NULL, "<img");
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `strtok` is a list of delimiter characters. Each of these will be used to split the string into tokens. I don't think it does what you think it does...

If you want to go and parse an html file into tokens, you could look into `lex`...

What is your desired output? Do you have a test case for your input?

Your code should produce the following:

**input:**

```
<html><img src="test.png"/></html>
```

**output:**

- ""
- "ht"
- "l>"
- " src=\"test.pn"
- "\"/>"
- "/ht"
- "l>"

I somehow don't think that is what you want...