# How to split string with string in C? (delimit as a string not set of delimiter chars)

Tags: c, string

How to split string with string in C?

In `strtok`, `delimit` arg treats as a set of delimiter chars.
I want to split string when found delimit `string`. (not set of delimit chars)

Is there a function like strtokstr?

```
char s[] = "1A2AB3AC";
strtok(s, "AB"); // split string when found "A" or "B" or "AB".

strtokstr(s, "AB") // I want to split string when found just "AB" (not include "A" or "B")
```

Comment: Nope. But there is a `strstr` that you can use to roll up your own tokenizer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17944619/971127

Comment: How do I do it? would you mind describing to me?

Comment: BLUEPIXY just gave you a link. So I suggest you go and upvote his answer there